# Data migration concept in databases

Tags: migration, database-migration, data-migration, data-conversion

i have a generic question about data migration/conversion.

here the situation:

```
i have data in a access db and want to migrate it into a oracle db. its not a 1 to 1 migration. i need to define which data should be imported into a specific oracle table and create some logic after that somehow.
```

do you have some ideas or a concept how to do this? maybe a checklist not that i forget something or i dont know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to run it just once and be done? Or do you need to set up a job that routinely transfers the data?   The keyword you might not be familiar with for googling is "ETL" - Extract, Transform, Load - and there are lots of products designed to handle ETL tasks.

Common sticking points are converting dates from one db to another and floating point numbers (especially currency.)  When you hit specific problems, post new questions.  There's a stackoverflow sister site, serverfault.com that might be a better fit for a lot of ETL questions.  The products you're working with are popular so the db experts there are likely to have quick answers on datatype issues.